# Volume Shadow Copy Service warning: VSS was denied access to the root of volume (Win 7 Home Premium)

Tags: permissions, root, vss

I am mystified by the following warning in the Event Viewer. It is very frequent and always the same. Can anyone explain this to me? Is it a cause for concern? Might it have anything to do with my backup application (Jungle Disk). You can find an evtx file [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxUowl9JZuG4ZDU2YzY5ZmUtNDdlYi00NjlmLTljODMtNDZlM2U4MjRhNmY0&hl=en&authkey=CKaAtPIB). Thanks very much.

Total number of events: 1

19433   /   02/08/11 15:00:01   /   Application

Source   : VSS

EventID  : 12348

Category :

Volume Shadow Copy Service warning: VSS was denied access to the root of volume \?\Volume{95eb80be-c226-11df-92ef-002564879bfe}.
Denying administrators from accessing volume roots can cause many unexpected failures, and will prevent VSS from functioning properly.  Check security on the volume, and try the operation again.

Operation:
   Removing auto-release shadow copies
   Loading provider

Context:
   Execution Context: System Provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this

> Event ID 12348
>
> Resolve:
>
> Ensure that VSS has access to the volume root directory
>
> If the Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) does not have access to the volume root directory, shadow copy creation on the volume will fail.
>
> To perform this procedure, you must have membership in Administrators, or you must have been delegated the appropriate authority.
>
> To ensure that VSS has access to the volume root directory:
>
> Open an elevated Command Prompt window. Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
>   Type icacls (VolumeRootPath) /grant system:f at the command prompt, where (VolumeRootPath) is the path to the volume root directory, for example, icacls C:\ /grant system:f
>
> For more information about the icacls command, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=104873.

.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364979(WS.10).aspx)

.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. In the following sentence in your reply, "Type icacls /grant system:f at the command prompt, where is the path to the volume root directory, for example, D:" there seems to be a word or words missing between the words "where" and "is"; the sentence just doesn't parse. Could you supply what's missing? Also, can you tell me how to determine what drive letter has been assigned (if any) to the volume with the GUID {95eb80be-c226-11df-92ef-002564879bfe}? I'm afraid what I have been able to find out on my own hasn't helped. Thanks again.

Comment: Normally it is Drive C: whatever the Operating system resides on. Click the "Source" link in my post for more information. I fixed my post also, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks very much. The icacls command ran successfully. Now we'll see if I get anymore VSS errors.

Comment: NOTE: for anyone who comes here to debug why Macrium Reflect is failing to clone a drive, this step followed by a **restart** of Windows appeared to let Macrium Reflect clone successfully.

Comment: Another note for folks trying to debug why Macrium Reflect is failing to clone a drive (as I just was). This did not work for me, and I ended up needing to use `diskpart` from the command line (as admin) to wipe the whole disk, create a new primary partition, and format it. Something like `diskpart` `list disk` `select disk 1` (or whatever your disk number is) `clean` `create partition primary` `format fs=ntfs`. One should be able to find more detailed step-by-step instructions by Googling "fully reset hard drive command line" or something similar. *NOTE: this wipes out all data on the drive.*